# SQL Server Command Line Install - How to change the edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, installation, scripting

I am creating a script to install SQL Server via the command line.

I cannot see a way to choose the edition I want to install. The GUI on my install media offers Evaluation, Developer or Express:

(When I choose Evaluation, I can enter the product code)

[image]

The ConfigurationFile.ini generated by the installer does not seem to have any sort of reference to the edition that is being installed. Once I run the installer, it installs standard edition (verified by `PRINT @@version`)

How can I specify the edition I wish to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some information about your question.

There is a parameter when you set up on the command line which is `/PID`.

Check out the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-ver15).

> Specifies the product key for the edition of SQL Server. If this
> parameter is not specified, Evaluation is used.

```
C:\SQLMedia\SQLServer2019> setup.exe /Q 
/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION="install" 
/PID="AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD-EEEEE" /FEATURES=SQL,AS,IS,Tools
/INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SQLSVCACCOUNT="MyDomain\MyAccount"
```

You can use this parameter with the product key.

**Evaluation**: `00000-00000-00000-00000-00000`

**Express**: `11111-00000-00000-00000-00000`

**Developer**: `22222-00000-00000-00000-00000`

*Excerpt from the [blog](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/04/14/sql-server-product-key-for-developer-edition-enterprise-evaluation-edition-and-express-edition/) of Pinal Dave.*

Comment: it works - thanks!